# Finding the condomain of $g(x) = 2^{r(x)}$, $r(x)$ being a quadratic function

Tags: calculus

> Let $r$ be the quadratic function represented in the graph below:
>   [image]
>
> What is the condomain of function $g$, defined by $g(x) = 2^{r(x)}$?
>
> a)$]-\infty,4]$  $$\\$$  b)$]0,4]$  $$\\$$  c)$]-\infty,2]$  $$\\$$ 
>   d)$]0,+\infty[$

If I understand it right, the domain of a function is all the inputs it can take, then condomain is all the inputs it cannot take. For example, the function $f(x) = \log(x)$ cannot take zero nor negative numbers as input, thus its condomain is $]-\infty,0]$.

However, in this case $2^y$ can take any number as input, so the condomain of $g(x)$ is the condomain of $r(x)$.

But $r(x)$ can also take any number as input... I think.

How do I solve this?

Comment: $r(x)$ ranges within $]-\infty,2]$, so $2^{]-\infty,2]}$ equals ... (b).

Comment: @MichaelHoppe What about the condomain?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codomain